# Special chars and HTML Markup issue in twig

Tags: php, twig

I write in admin: **ľščťžýáíé**

I try this code:

```
{{ top_content[lang]['description'] | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}
```

Got result in front: **Ä¾Å¡ÄÅ¥Å¾Ã½Ã¡Ã­Ã©**

if I try `{{ top_content[lang]['description'] }}` So, it does work. but display html markup.

```
<p>ľščťžýáíé<br></p>
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand  second  example  is nearly ok ,
what about

```
{{ top_content[lang]['description']  | raw }}
```

or

```
{{ top_content[lang]['description']  | striptags }}
```

Comment: Hmm... It should... Did you cleared cache after you changed code ? (Twig have its own cache system )